# How to untap all unused brew taps?

Tags: macos, homebrew

`brew bundle dump` outputs a bunch of taps for apps I installed, then uninstalled.

I could just try untapping every tap, and brew will refuse to untap anything in use. Like this without `echo`:

```
brew bundle dump --file=- --no-upgrade | grep '^tap' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L 1 echo brew untap
brew untap 1password/tap
brew untap blakek/blakek
brew untap buo/cask-upgrade
brew untap domt4/autoupdate
brew untap hashicorp/tap
brew untap homebrew/bundle
brew untap homebrew/cask
brew untap homebrew/cask-fonts
brew untap homebrew/core
brew untap homebrew/services
brew untap isen-ng/dotnet-sdk-versions
brew untap jakehilborn/jakehilborn
brew untap withgraphite/tap
```

This correctly untaps most things, except it also untaps everything from `homebrew`:

```
$ brew untap "domt4/autoupdate"
Untapping domt4/autoupdate...
Untapped 1 command (280 files, 727.4KB).

$ brew untap "hashicorp/tap"
Error: Refusing to untap hashicorp/tap because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:
vault

$ brew untap "homebrew/bundle"
Untapping homebrew/bundle...
Untapped 1 command (807 files, 2.3MB).
```

---

Is the best solution to do the above, except also `grep -v homebrew`?

Answer (score 1):

Since [version 4.0.0](https://brew.sh/2023/02/16/homebrew-4.0.0), Homebrew will now fetch all of its own repositories using a JSON API rather than the much slower git tap. So you can now remove all your homebrew taps.

Comment: Thanks for the context! I tried this, but then running `brew bundle dump` gave the error: "Error: `brew bundle` is unavailable because homebrew/bundle was manually untapped. Run `brew tap homebrew/bundle` to reenable `brew bundle`." --so I kept this one

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with brew bundle, but based on the error message it seems you have to tap it to use it, so keeping it should be fine.

Comment: can we even untap `homebrew-cask`?  I tried that but `brew doctor` complained

Comment: You should be able to since those are also in the JSON API now, what is the message `brew doctor` gives?

Answer (score 0):

`brew update` can untap outdated commands/formulae

```
...
==> homebrew/core is old and unneeded, untapping to save space...
Untapping homebrew/core...
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
Untapped 3 commands and 6533 formulae (7,531 files, 799.2MB).
...
```

Comment: I don't understand, is this a new feature? I'm using brew autoupdate and wasn't seeing automatically untapping... Can you elaborate? `brew update --help` doesn't  give any suggestions for options to untap taps that aren't used.

Comment: @CarlWalsh Updated with my terminal output when `brew update`

Comment: thanks! I tested this isn't working for me... 1) `brew bundle dump` doesn't show "withgraphite/tap" 2) `brew tap withgraphite/tap` 3) now bundle dump shows withgraphite 4) `brew update` just shows `Already up-to-date.` 5) bundle dump still shows withgraphite.

Comment: maybe you have a different env var set? My `printenv | grep -i brew` only has shows `HOMEBREW_AUTOREMOVE=1`. `brew --config` doesn't show anything strange. I'm running version 4.1.18-29-g2b747f4.

Comment: Tried tapping `homebrew/core` to see if it was special-cased to be untapped, but was not removed by `brew update`. Tried running `brew upgrade` but that did not trigger untap.

Comment: I use `Homebrew 4.1.18`. The V4 upgrade notes [here](https://brew.sh/2023/02/16/homebrew-4.0.0/) say: `Unless you are developing formulae or casks, you can brew untap homebrew/core and brew untap homebrew/cask to save some space.`